# Почему не работает id3_get_tag?

Tags: php

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function id3_get_tag() in /*pages\blocks\music\music.php:101 Stack trace: #0 /*\pages\music.php(5): include() #1 /*index.php(48): include('D:\orion.com\pa...') #2 {main} thrown in /*pages\blocks\music\music.php on line 101

Как средствами php можно достать содержимое mp3? желательно без фреймов

Answer (score 1):

У вас просто нет этой функции. Следовательно нет расширения.

http://php.net/manual/ru/id3.installation.php - вот инструкция, установите и все заработает.

Comment: Есть ли варианты работы с id3 без подключения отдельных модулей?

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев Возможно Вам подойдет этот способ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709584/how-to-get-meta-data-out-of-mp3-files (лично не тестил)

Comment: Не хочу создавать отдельную тему, слишком пройстой вопрос наверное.... регулярное выражение на проверку только длины можете написать? (без ограничения различных символов)

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев Длины чего? Побольше информации дайте, какой длины, напишем

Comment: В итоге он использовал .. .http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Comment: if(!preg_match("/^{4,10000}$/", $data['content'])){ 4-10 000 символов

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев Для длины строки лучше использовать `mb_strlen`